# Product of PD matrices is PD, once again

Tags: linear-algebra

I see on wikipedia that the product of two symmetric positive definite matrices is also positive definite if the resulting product is normal.
I've seen the proof for the same case with PSD matrices in "On a product of positive semidefinite matrices", by A.R. Meenakshi, C. Rajian, but I don't manage to find the proof for PD case in some "quotable" source.

So is anyone aware of one?

Thnx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The reason might be that the proof is (almost) straightforward : 
Given $A$ and $B$ two positive definite matrices, denote $S=A^{1/2}$ the square root of A.
Then $S$ is also invertible and :
$$AB=S(SBS)S^{-1}$$

Thus AB is similar to $SBS$ which is a positive symmetric matrix, and this shows that the product AB has only positive eigenvalues even though it is not symmetric.

Note that you just need A to be positive definite, B can be positive semi-definite.

P.S : by the way, the idea of the proof is to change the canonical dot product to another one for which AB is now a symmetric matrix :
$$ \langle X,Y\rangle_A = X^T A^{-1} Y$$
Then 
$$\langle ABX,Y\rangle=X^TBAA^{-1}Y=X^TA^{-1}ABY=\langle X,ABY\rangle$$